# git push returns remote: Permission denied , URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, git-push

i've cloned this repo

```
git clone https://github.com/arunavo4/sol-sell-escrow/
```

and after building&deploying it , i noticed in the Development Cycle it says

```
# Push your code to the main branch to auto-deploy on Netlify.
git push
```

so i just did a `git push` and i got

```
remote: Permission to arunavo4/sol-sell-escrow.git denied to Hretic. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/arunavo4/sol-sell-escrow/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

i've searched and saw lots people asking this question but it was mostly about their own repo , i dont own this repo ... can i push to it ?

i dont work with git much , im pretty lost  ! some extra info :

```
git remote -v 
origin https://github.com/arunavo4/sol-sell-escrow (fetch) 
origin https://github.com/arunavo4/sol-sell-escrow (push)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont own this repo ... can i push to it ?

No, you can't. As you rightly say, you don't own it.

You could, however, *fork* the repo on GitHub. The fork would belong to you, and you could clone that and subsequently push to it, if you like.

Comment: im not good at git terminology , but if i fork and then push it it wont be in the main branch as author suggested , would it ? 
i suppose it would be my own main branch right ?

Comment: I'm not good at whatever the world is in which this code operates. So I don't understand the purpose of the push. But the author could never have been suggesting "push to _my_ copy of the repo", because that would change the author's copy of the repo! If you were allowed to push direct to the author's copy you could push any sort of garbage you wanted and deface the author's work.

Comment: thanx that's what i thought